# Is there a way to convert a Geopy location to a short address string?

Tags: python, geo, geopy

I have a geopy location that I would like to represent as a string.

I've tried using `str(location.address)`, but this gives a way too long string e.g. `48, De Keyserlei, Statiekwartier, Antwerpen, Vlaanderen, 2018, België - Belgique - Belgien`

After some research online I found a way to get the location as dictionary, so I could create my own address by adding the values of this dictionary.

Then the problem is that e.g. not all addresses have a street, or some have a town instead of a city, and there are a lot more exceptions, too many to check for everything whether it's in the dictionary.

Here is some sample code to test:

```py
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="[PlaceHolder]")
location = geolocator.reverse("51.217497747238106, 4.418478198686335")
print(str(location.address))  # Way too long address


def location_str(location):
    addr_dict = location.raw["address"]
    location_str = addr_dict["road"] + " " \
                   + addr_dict["house_number"] + ", " \
                   + addr_dict["postcode"] + " " \
                   + addr_dict["city"]
    return location_str


print(location_str(location))  # Works as I want it to be

# Let's try a different address
location = geolocator.reverse("51.217497747238106, 4.418478198686335")
print(location_str(location))  # KeyError: 'road' (because the address doesn't have a road)
```

So, do you know a way to represent this location as a short, readable string?

Comment: You can use [dict.get](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get), e.g., `... + addr_dict.get("city", addr_dict["town"])`. You can also check first if some key is in your dictionary, e.g., `print(addr_dict['state'] if 'state' in addr_dict else 'no state information')`

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat brute-force way to handle having different keys associated with the same value, you could expand each dictionary into what effectively is a many-to-one dictionary.

Snce I don't have `geopy` installed, I can't run your code, but hopefully the following is close enough to give you the idea of what I am suggesting.

Note that at least one of the keys in each group of equivalents must exist in the address directory — otherwise an exception will be raised.

```
geolocator = {
    "51.217497747238106, 4.418478198686335":
        dict(road='De Keyserlei', house_number='48', postcode='PC1234', city='Antwerpen'),
    "51.217497747238107, 4.418478198686335":
        dict(street='De Keyserlei', house_number='49', postcode='PC1235', town='Antwerpen'),
}

EQUIV_KEYS = [('city', 'town', 'village'),
              ('road', 'street', 'avenue'),]


def expand_keys(addr_dict, equiv_keys):
    res = addr_dict.copy()
    for group in equiv_keys:
        for key in group:
            if key in addr_dict:
                match = key
                break
        else:
            raise KeyError(f'None of the keys in group {group} exist')

        # Set the values of the other keys to the one that matched.
        for key in group:
            if key != match:
                res[key] = addr_dict[match]

    return res

def location_str(location):
    addr_dict = geolocator[location]
    equiv_dict = expand_keys(addr_dict, EQUIV_KEYS)

    location_str = (f'{equiv_dict["road"]} {equiv_dict["house_number"]}, '
                    f'{equiv_dict["postcode"]} {equiv_dict["city"]}')
    return location_str


location1 = "51.217497747238106, 4.418478198686335"
print(location_str(location1))

location2 = "51.217497747238107, 4.418478198686335"
print(location_str(location2))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the function I wrote to solve the problem. It might not be the most ideal solution, but it does the job.

```py
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from geopy.exc import GeocoderTimedOut

def get_from_dict(dictionary, *args):
    for word in args:
        if word in dictionary:
            return dictionary[word]
    return ""

def addr(lat, long):
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="[PlaceHolder]")

    try:
        location = geolocator.reverse(str(lat) + ", " + str(long))
    except GeocoderTimedOut:
        return "Geocoder timed out :/"

    addr_dict = location.raw["address"]

    location_str = ""

    # Address line
    location_str += get_from_dict(addr_dict, "road", "avenue", "street", "cycleway", "pedestrian") + " "
    # Number
    location_str += get_from_dict(addr_dict, "house_number")
    # Only add a ", " if you've already added something so far (that's not a space)
    location_str += ", " if len(location) > 1 else ""
    # Postcode
    location_str += get_from_dict(addr_dict, "postcode") + " "
    # City
    location_str += get_from_dict(addr_dict, "city", "town")

    # When nothing could be added
    if len(location_str) <= 4:
        location_str = str(location.address)

    return location_str

print(addr(51.221225, 4.399826))
```